# Is there a known construction for heavy topologies of all sizes?

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples

Given a set $A$ is there a known way to find a topological space $X$ such that $|A|=|X|<w(X)$?

Here $w(X)$ is the weight of the topological space.

This is clearly impossible for finite sets $A$. We know it is possible for $A=\mathbb Z$ because of the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105117/countable-topological-spaces-of-uncountable-weight).

Is there a general construction for any infinite set? Is it even known if such a space exists for every infinite $A$? Has a contruction been found for $\mathbb R$ for example?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U$ be a (free) ultrafilter on an infinite set $X$ which contains only sets of cardinality $|X|$ (that is, it is a normal ultrafilter). Put $\tau = U \cup \{\varnothing\}$; this is clearly a topology.

There is no base $B$ for $\tau$ with $|B|=|X|$ as every such base must have cardinality at least $|X|^+$ by a diagonal argument.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to use a "diagonal argument" to prove that every uniform ultrafilter on $X$ has weight bigger than $|X|$. (That being said, I can prove that it's true for *some* uniform ultrafilters using independent sets, and this is good enough for an affirmative answer to the original question.) Am I missing something?

Comment: @WillBrian To show that no family of $|X|$ sets in $U$ can be a base, enumerate the family as $(X_\xi)_{\xi<|X|}$ and then, by induction on $\xi$, pick $x_\xi$ and $y_\xi$ in $X_\xi$, distinct from each other and from earlier choices. Then each $X_\xi$ meets both the set of $x_\xi$'s and its complement, so the $X_\xi$'s can't be a base for $U$. Then it follows that they can't be a base for the topology either.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks for clearing that up. It is indeed a (pretty straightforward) diagonal argument, and now I'm not really sure what I was thinking when I wrote my comment.

Comment: Shouldn't "normal" be "uniform" here? I have always seen "normal" mean "closed under diagonal interesections"

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X73900299) by I. Juhasz and K. Kunen for a construction of a **Hausdorff** space $X$ with $d(X)=\kappa$, $|X|=2^{2^\kappa}$ and $w(X)=2^{2^{2^\kappa}}$, where $\kappa$ is any cardinal given in advance.